# out of memory exception on high load to data table

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need to load some data from Oracle using VB.NET that needs to be formatted as mainframe friendly (leading zeros and trailing spaces).

The data needs to be written into a text file.

I have total 40 million records, so I encountered an out of memory exception.

Is there any way to handle huge data in a datatable?

Comment: Yes, buy more memory or select less data.

Comment: Why on earth would you want that data in a DataTable? Select, convert and write in chunks. Pretty basic stuff, try searching.

Comment: What is the special need to involve VB.NET in between? You can directly format and write file in oracle!

Comment: on a side note - careless use of String may fill the memory very quick for such a high number of recorde. String is immutable and every add (+) or replace operation will create a copy

Comment: Please, always post your code and re-read [ask]. Obviously the data table will be massive, how big is the txt file?

Comment: I need to write the oracle data to text file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not load a `DataTable` with so many records, select what you really need. But if you have to write them to a tex-file you can either use oracle directly:

- [Writing data to a text file from Oracle](https://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/04/28/writing-data-to-a-text-file-from-oracle/)

or you can write one line after the other and use a `OracleDataReader` to stream each record. On that way you don't need to load all into memory.

Here's an example where i show how to write to a tab delimited text file:

```
Dim queryString = "SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, OrderColumn FROM TableName Order By OrderColumn"
Using con = New OracleConnection(connectionString)
    Using cmd = New OracleCommand(queryString, con)
        con.Open()
        Using writer = New StreamWriter("c:\temp\FileName.txt")
            ' Headerline: '
            writer.WriteLine("Column1\tColumn2\tColumn3\OrderColumn")
            Using rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While rd.read()
                    writer.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", rd("Column1"), rd("Column2"), rd("Column3"), rd("OrderColumn"))
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Thank you so much for providing the solution

Comment: @user96888: note that i haven't installed oracle and could also not test the approach. But it might show you how to make it working.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use DataTable. Use DataReader, read one record, format it and write it directly to file. Then read next one, and so on.

Comment: Ya .. this idea is good instead of writing into data table i can write into file. Is it safe to open the connection with more time ?

Comment: You have probably no other choice. It's good idea to talk with you DBA and ask him, if you can use SnapshotIsolationLevel for transaction, becase this will not block other jobs to access the table data in time, you are processing them with DataReader.